# Is it possible to create an executable from my django project with connection to a mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, django

i'm new in python, i would like create an executable-installer of my django project, i would like that my client with double-click runs this program and open his browser with my project running on his **local server**, and that he **can access to mysql database**, Thanks.
I've searched on internet about python to exe scripts, PyInstaller, but I can't find how to run the server and connect to the database in an executable.

Comment: If you want something managed that also replicates a production environment, I suggest you look into Docker.
If you want to simply create a startup script in local I suggest you simply create a .bat or .sh file with the commands needed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I tried to create the .bat to run the server, but it doesn't run "python manage.py runserver", this is my code @ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe / C "python manage.py runserver && cd C: \ Users \ User1 \ Desktop \ MyProject && C:"
start C: \ "Program Files (x86)" \ Google \ Chrome \ Application \ chrome.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" , .I would appreciate an answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to prepare your application and embed a production-ready web server such as uvicorn. Afterward, you must bundle this with a tool such as pyinstaller. This can be quite a hassle due to the large number of dependencies.